# How to use tar with --listed-incremental option

Tags: tar

I am trying to run the following command.

```
tar zcf ~/BAKUPS/test.tgz --listed-incremental=~/BAKUPS/snapshot ~/test/
```

It does create the tgz file, but I get the following errors.

```
tar: ~/BAKUPS/snapshot: Cannot open: No such file or directory
tar: Removing leading `/' from member names
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I am using Lubuntu 13.04, and have tar (GNU tar) 1.26. I get the error even if I manually touch the snapshot file first. I have been using this command on another machine (but I don't remember if the version of tar is different there.

Comment: Where is "~"?  That is, what happens if you run:
    (cd ~;pwd)